Composing multiple <use>'s (layers) within an <svg>
I want to create an image, say, a crowned stag inside a flamed heart.
Both the elements are defined as shown:
<body>
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" class="d-none">
        <defs>
            …
            <symbol id="bi-heart" class="bi bi-heart" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="…"/>
            </symbol>
            <symbol id="bi-stag" class="bi bi-stag" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                <path d="…"/>
            </symbol>
            …
        </defs>
    </svg>
…
</body>

I combine them as this:
<div>
    <svg width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor">
        <use href="#bi-heart"></use>
        <use href="#bi-stag"></use>
    </svg>
</div>

So far so good. But now I'd like the stag to be N times smaller, and centered hz/vt (or, even better, having relative offsets).
How to achieve this?

apply a scale transform and/or a translate transform.

You can use x and y attributes to position the . Also since the symbol has a viewBox you can give the  a width and a height.

Kudo to @enxaneta, the answer is:
<div>
    <svg width="64" height="64" fill="currentColor">
        <!-- 100% -->
        <use href="#bi-heart" width="64" height="64"></use>
        <!-- 50%, centered -->
        <use href="#bi-stag"  width="32" height="32" x="16" y="16"></use>
    </svg>
</div>


You can accept your own answer since it resolved your problem.
